# resolve.conf issue in 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: networking, server, dns

`resolve.conf` is displaying some HTML code and I can't seem to correct the issue. I've added DNS entries to `/etc/network/interfaces` and `resolvconf -u` showed a missing symlink; so I `rm`'d `resolve.conf` and ran `dpkg-reconfigure resolveconf` and rebooted. I'm still seeing this (where 'x.x.x.x' = correct DNS IP & domain.name = correct domain):

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver x.x.x.x
search domain.name.net 0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>404 - File or directory not found.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
background-color:#555555;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>
  <h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>404 - File or directory not found.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
background-color:#555555;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>
  <h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have a look at the file */etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf*, do you have a strange setting inside?

Comment: I don't see anything odd here, config is set to static IP to btw

Comment: Most everything is commented out

Answer (score 0):

You could try making a script, and run it type this:

```
#/bin/sh
   [default]
   case [!$] in
      /bin/sh
      networkname="true"
      networkname="ip adr here"
      nmcli nm networkname vpn
      resolve.confirm ip adr here
   endl
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: Thanks Michael, would prefer to find the root cause...its a real head scratcher...